# Google App Engine Python python email not working

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

My application was working ok for almost a year now, but suddenly it can't send emails. There are no exceptions raised, everything seems ok, but the mails are not delivered I've checked the entire mailbox, spam folders and everything. Here is the sending code:

```
mail.send_mail(sender="nikola825@gmail.com",  #this is my email, I am the admin
               to=email,
               subject="Account verification",
               body=emailContentsTXT)
```

The call returns successfully, no exceptions are thrown. The number of sent emails in the Quotas dashboard gets increased when I try to send the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of errors and the incrementing of the sent emails in the Quotas indicate that message sending works fine.

The only way to determine why the messages are not reaching the destination is to check the bounced emails. Your app needs to be [configured to receive and handle the bounced emails](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/bounce):

> To configure your app to receive bounced email notifications:
>
> 1.Add the following to your app.yaml file to enable notification:
>
> ```
> inbound_services:
> - mail_bounce
> ```
>
> 2.Also in app.yaml, declare a mapping between /_ah/bounce and the bounce notification handler in your code, for example:
>
> ```
> - url: /_ah/bounce
>   script: handle_bounced_email.app
>   login: admin
> ```

The mentioned doc contains examples of possible bounced message handlers as well.

**Update:** After the OP's observation that the issue seems caused by a URL (to an `appspot.com` domain) inside the email I noticed [this GAE issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12786) (still open and with quite recent activity) which appears a perfect match.

Comment: I have set up the bounce handler and I'm not getting any bounce notifications. There are no requests to '/_ah/bounce' in the logs. I have tried sending emails to several different addresses, they couldn't all get bounced.

Comment: Sometimes the bounced messages can come after hours or even days, depending on the cause of the bounce - usually after the automatic retries of the mail delivery systems hit a certain retry limit.

Comment: I just found out that the emails that contain appspot.com links don't get sent for some reason. This is a verification email so it contains a link to my site. If I remove the link the email gets sent and delivered normally.

Comment: Nice catch! Much more focused question now. You'd still need to get a bounced message to get a clear idea where is the email dropped. Unless it's dropped "silently", in which case it may be very difficult to find out.

Comment: Yes, the bug link you posted is the exact problem I'm having. Thank you. I guess I'have to find another email service.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I've sent a complaint to the App Engine team, and they fixed the problem after a few days, the emails are working now.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11500981) on Hacker News about this.   Evidently anti-spam measures by Google have been silently deleting email sent from AppEngine.

A Google Engineer says that they're working with people on a case-by-case basis so if you're having a problem, you should probably contact their support.