# Google App Engine Send Mail Not Working

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use Python and Google App Engine to send automated emails to certain addresses:

```
    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender="noreply@"+app_identity.get_application_id()+".appspotmail.com",subject="Verify Email",to="Bob Person <bob.person@gmail.com>")
        message.body = "Hey, someone tried to register an account with this email."
        message.send()
```

I have removed my own email and replaced it with Bob Person, but my email is correct. Also, I can confirm that using an invalid sender email gives an invalid sender error, so that isn't the problem. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Did you check https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/#who_can_send_mail?

Comment: @DanCornilescu yep, I think the sender is correct

Comment: BTW - what does "send mail not working" means exactly?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Well, no errors or bounces, yet the mail doesn't deliver :(

Comment: That's trickier, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522924/4495081 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35727562/4495081.

Comment: @DanCornilescu aha, yes all my emails would have had an appspot link in, and that would only have been changed after 10 tries. I'll test that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the solution was to remove an appspot.com link. I ended up using a bitly API to replace the links with bitly ones. Thank you everyone for helping with this one, it'd be really helpful if this behaviour was officially documented.

Answer (score 2):

The sender's email ID should be added as a owner in the appengine project or use service account ID as sender.

Comment: Yeah, I did use the correct format for the email, my project is airborn-clan, and the email sender is noreply@airborn-clan.appspotmail.com, which is valid. Is there another stage?

Comment: 1 more thing, check quota.
Mail API limits you to send only  100 mail per day, If you are exceeding that use sendgrid instead.

Comment: Actually, without billing enabled, the quota is just 10 per day.  Easy to hit the limit when testing.  Check your quotas, or try again tomorrow